# How to have a transparent backup server for SVN

Tags: backup, svn

A few friends and I were thinking about a project. We would need a server to for a SVN repository and storage for basic things, that we grab once in a while (lets say they are all art and sound files).

How would I set the server so if it goes down for whatever reasons (a random unknown surprise) to have everything use the backup server transparently and not have any problems?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SVN Sync is what you need for backups - but you cannot do the transparent switch over for writing. The best idea I can think of is to use modsvn on multiple load balanced apache servers and a network mounted repo. I do recall some issues when using nfs, but you can google for them. For true multiple server syncing, git or some other dvcs would be the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

I have a pretty good solution in place that works well for me.

Basically, you all get a [dropbox](http://www.getdropbox.com/) account which gives you 2GB free (and more GB if you need for very little outlay). Then you setup your SVN repository inside a folder in the dropbox and you share that folder with your friends. You will EACH have a fully up to date copy of the SVN Repository on the local machines and as soon as you check-in those changes get transported across the wire to your friends, who can check out of their local repository to get your changes. It's like getting the benefits of distributed version control for free!

If any of your machines go down, it won't affect the others, and it's also a pristine backup of everything you're doing in there up in the cloud.

I hope this helps you - it has worked perfectly for us for months now.

Comment: What happens when two people commits to the SVN server at the same time? would it not update the home copy, update to dropbox then either allow the 2nd one to replace the first (losing changes) or just have a conflict that needs to be fixed?

Comment: Why not switch to a real DVCS instead? As acid said, having to deal with a potential conflict is just not worth it.

Comment: Hmm, and what would be when one of your customer delete all repo from dropbox folder?